# What is the difference between && and and in C#9?

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

Now that there exists a keyword `and` in C# 9, when should I use `and` and when should I use `&&`?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#pattern-matching-enhancements there are different use cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are different operators for different use cases

`&&` works on boolean values, as known before

`and` works on pattern matching expressions and is meant to combine two of these via logical conjuction

Same applies to `||` and `or`, and `!` and `not`

Comment: Why did they introduce new operators instead of using the boolean operators?

Answer (score 1):

`&&` `||` `!`: Boolean operators over bool

`and` `or` `not`: Boolean operators over patterns